# How to stream from/to stdin/stdout to/from S3 using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm looking for help figuring out how to use boto3 to stream objects from/to stdin and stdout. The AWS S3 cp command can do it, by specifying '-' as the filename, but looking at the boto3 documentation I don't understand how.

Answer (score 1):

To an object to `STDOUT`, you can open an S3 object as a stream

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.download_fileobj('your_bucket', 'your_key', sys.stdout)
```

to upload from `STDIN` it's almost the same, but depending on what you want to do you can make your life easier (nb `python 3` here`)

```
some_stuff = input('type something: ')
s3.put_object(**{
    'Bucket': 'your_bucket',
    'Key': 'your_key',
    'Body': some_stuff
})
```

Answer (score -7):

This maybe?

```
import sys
sys.stdin, sys.stdout
```